# How to check if Arrays inside Object are Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my sample data. I want to check if Arrays inside an object are empty or not.

```
{
  collection: Array(0), 
  availability: Array(0), 
  gender: Array(0),
  brand: Array(0),
}
```

Following is the code that I am using right now (copied from some other stackoverflow link).

```
function objectIsEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).every(function(key) {
      var val = obj[key];  

      if (Array.isArray(val) && val.length === 0) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
}
```

Above code is working fine.
My main question is there any cleaner way to check all empty arrays inside an Object through jQuery code like we use jQuery.isEmptyObject() to check the Empty object?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ES8 has `Object.values`, which is better than `Object.keys` if you just want the values. You can also directly return the `Array.isArray(val) && val.length === 0` test, and concisely return if you want:

```
const objectIsEmpty = obj => Object.values(obj).every(
    val => Array.isArray(val) && val.length === 0
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all the returns and assignments. e.g.

```
function objectIsEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).every(key => 
      Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].length;
    );
}
```